What is so special about eigenvector that it behaves like a pivot of linear transformation?
What is so special about eigenvector of matrix $A$ such that matrix $A$ fails to change its direction during linear transformation?
The eigenvector (say of matrix $A$) is such a vector in the vector space that it will only shrink or expand but not change its direction. It is like a pivot of transformation performed by $A$.
What allows eigenvector to be a pivot? It behaves as if it is independent of the transformation. Let's say transformation by multiplication with a $2 \times 2$ matrix changes $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath\,}$ of cartesian $2$-D space, then how is it possible that eigenvector, which is composed of combination of $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath\,}$, manages to stay unaffected?

It is defined that way. When $Ax = \lambda x$, the matrix behaves like a scalar and $x$ is the eigenvector.

@CroCo the color red is red because it is defined that way. yet it shouldn't stop you from exploring the light wavelength that makes it red.

^you are mixing human definitions with things observed in nature. "The eigenvector (say of matrix $A$) is such a vector in the vector space that it will only shrink or expand but not change its direction" Basically you are looking for vectors that satisfy this equation $Ax=\lambda x$.

I suppose one way to look at it is that it's the vector that has the right combination of $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$ such that the stretching and skewing caused by $A$ on each of those basis vectors balances out just right.
We find the eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ by solving the equation $A\mathbf{v} = \lambda\mathbf{v}$, which can also be written as $(A - \lambda I) \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$, so once we have an eigenvalue $\lambda$ this is just a set of linear equations that we can easily solve for $\mathbf{v}$.
You can also look at it the other way around - if we have two linearly independent eigenvectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ with associated eigenvalues $\mu$ and $\lambda$, then we can use them as a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, meaning that any vector $\mathbf{w}$ can be written as a linear combination of them. If we write one the standard basis vectors as $\hat\imath = a_1 \mathbf{u} + a_2 \mathbf{v}$, then $A \hat\imath = A(a_1\mathbf{u} + a_2\mathbf{v}) = a_1 \mu \mathbf{u} + a_2 \lambda \mathbf{v}$, so the skewing caused by $A$ is really a result of the different mixture of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ getting scaled by different amounts thanks to their eigenvalues. In other words, in the $(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v})$ basis, $A$ is just a scaling factor of $(\mu, \lambda)$.

"the vector that has the right combination of ı̂  and ȷ̂  such that the stretching and skewing caused by  on each of those basis vectors balances out just right." can you please provide an example to illustrate this intrinsic property for real eigenvector? Another point is that lets say I perform simple 45 degree rotation of 2D plane such that new j^ is (a,a) and new i^ is (a,-a) where a is sqrt(1/2). Now eigenvector contains an element that belongs to complex plane . so real plane rotates along a pivot thats in complex 2D plane? how does it fit together

I'd love to provide a diagram, but I don't really have that kind of skill unfortunately. And yes, if you've got complex eigenvalues then this is happening in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is harder to visualise.

The key is in the definition of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors. In typical linear algebra textbooks, the eigenvalues/eigenvectors are defined as follows
Applied Linear Algebra, second edition by Olver and Shakiban

Definition8.2. Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. A scalar $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue of $A$ if there is a non-zero vector
$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}} \neq \boldsymbol{0}$, called an eigenvector,
such that  $$ A\boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}} = \lambda\boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}. $$

LINEAR ALGEBRA A Geometric Approach, second edition by Shifrin and Adams

Definition. Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. A nonzero vector $ \boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}} \in V$ is called an
eigenvector of $T$ if there is a scalar $\lambda$ so that
$T(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}) = \lambda \boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}$. The
scalar $\lambda$ is called the associated eigenvalue of $T$.

The above definitions answer your questions.
